# Android dynamic query sql using like

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I would make a query using `like` , using the % and a dynamic string, but i can't do it correctly.
I have a:

```
public Cursor query(String s)
 {
String whereClause=COL_ATTRIBUTI + " like '%?%'";
String[] whereArgs=new String[] {s};
 return  getWritableDatabase().query(TABELLA_RICETTE,null,whereClause,whereArgs,null,null,null);
}
```

COL_ATTRIBUTI is the name of a column and TABELLA_RICETTE the name of the table.
I would like to obtain all the thing that have `s` somewhere, so i use the %. but my app crash. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put the `%` wildcards in the argument if you are using the `?` placeholders:

```
String whereClause = COL_ATTRIBUTI + " like '?'";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {"%" + s + "%"};
```

Comment: i wrote String whereClause = COL_ATTRIBUTI + " like ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {"%" + s + "%"};